# Harbor 2.5.0 behind Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, harbor

I installed Harbor in a server inside the company farm and I can use it without problem through https://my-internal-server.com/harbor.

I tried to add the reverse proxy rules to Apache to access it through the public server for harbor, v2, chartrepo, service endpoints, like https://my-public-server.com/harbor, but this doesn't work.

For example:

```
  ProxyPass      /harbor   https://eslregistry.eng.it/harbor
  ProxyPassReverse  /harbor https://eslregistry.eng.it/harbor
```

I also set in harbor.yaml:

- external_url: https://my-public-server.com

When I try to access to https://my-public-server.com/harbor with the browser I see a Loading... page and **404** errors for static resources because it tries to get them with this GET:
https://my-public-server.com/scripts.a459d5a2820e9a99.js

How can I configure it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the whole domain, not only the path. Take a look at the official Nginx config to have an idea how this might look like.

```
upstream harbor {
  server harbor_proxy_ip:8080;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name harbor.mycomp.com;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/conf.d/mycomp.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/conf.d/mycomp.com.key;

    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://harbor/;
        proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
    }
```

Note that you should disable proxy or buffering